# Laravel - input request handling for global pagination

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

So I am creating an api in Laravel and a majority of the calls being made to it are requests for sortable / filterable / paginated data that will be displayed in data tables. I would like to create "something" that checks every request (sounds like middleware maybe??) and rips out the appropriate sorting / filtering / pagination data and stores it ...."somewhere".

My question is what would be that "something" (middleware? trait?) and in implementing it where would be a good place to store said information. Obviously not in a global variable....if it was a trait maybe I would store it in class properties? I am grasping at straws here and just need a point in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Laravel 5 you can easily setup whole thing in the middleware directory located in `app/http/Middleware`. You create new class there, register it in `app/Http/Kernel.php` file in `$middleware` property and use your newly running middleware however you like.

Super simple example:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class StoreInfo
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Tear your $request apart here and store however you need.
    }

}
```

As usually - it is advised to do `composer dump-autoload` after creating new file.

Comment: I agree that using middleware is a possibility. When thinking about that though I was wondering where I would store the stuff I ripped out of the request?

Comment: @BillGarrison, in the Database, in Redis, even in log file if you want to. I don't know what your requirements are and how you want to use that info.